# No place to specify iOS Bundle Signing and Provisioning in Visual Studio 2022 and MAUI

Tags: ios, xamarin, signing, maui, visual-studio-2022

Since MAUI integrates all platform targets under one project, there seems to be no UI to specify iOS Bundle signing, (like it was in pre-MAUI Xamarin, see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/get-started/installation/device-provisioning/automatic-provisioning?tabs=windows).

Is there a solution for this or a workaround?

Comment: Have the same question.  Not able to deploy this to the iOS local device otherwise.

Comment: Still the latest Preview Version of VS for Mac 2022 does not have option to set Provisioning profile and Certificates.

Answer (score 2):

Remember that at the time of writing neither .NET MAUI or the tooling to support it is ready yet. This feature will come (back) also for .NET MAUI, but simply has not been implemented yet in the current previews.

This is specifically about your question about the UI part. Of course, all the data is right there in the `info.plist` file under the Platforms/iOS folder. You can edit the XML there from within Visual Studio or with any text editor.

You can find a reference to the keys for the `info.plist` file in the Docs or click through to the Apple documentation for it, here: https://learn.microsoft.com/xamarin/ios/deploy-test/provisioning/infoplist-reference

Comment: Yes, I agree and am aware of it.  The reason I posted the question was I thought  that setting was indeed there and I was simply not finding it.

Comment: Love your stuff Gerald - great YouTube site, but how can your answer be correct?  Doesn't it have to exist to deploy to iOS devices - so just more info is needed?

Comment: Thanks @drewid! The question is specifically about the UI being there. The UI is not there. Of course all the info to deploy your app is there right in the info.plist file. If you don't mind editing XML, you can change it. But again, that was not the question :)

Comment: Updated my answer a bit to be more complete

Comment: Thanks @GeraldVersluis!  Yes, makes sense. Thanks for the updated answer is a huge help. As always you are awesome!

Answer (score 0):

You can add:

```
<key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
<string>com.yourAppName</string>
```

to Info.plst.